# How to seperate function with await

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I just switch from php into full time js. I try to **clean code** in javascript function but still confuse how to deal with it

```
for(let i in allEmpData) {
    let emp = allEmpData[i]
    if(empData == null) {
      const addEmp = new Employee()
      this.addEmpFn(addEmp, emp)
    }
    if(empData != null) {
      this.addEmpFn(empData, emp)
    }
 }
```

I call function addEmpFn  because I put create/update code in thier here is my function addEmpFn

```
 addEmpFn(empData, emp) {
    empData.name = emp.name
    return await empData.save()
  }
```

the error said :

Unexpected token return await

I want to do something like this but In the clean code , seperate function

```
 for(let i in allEmpData) {
    const empData =  await Employee.query()
                                  .where('id',1)
                                  .first();
    let emp = allEmpData[i]
    if(empData == null) {
      const addEmp = new Employee()
      addEmp.name = emp.name
      return await empData.save()
    }
    if(empData != null) {
      empData.name = emp.name
      return await empData.save()
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign function as async as follows:

```
async addEmpFn(empData, emp) {
    empData.name = emp.name
    return await empData.save()
}
```

Comment: why you need an async await here?

Answer (score 3):

await keyword only works inside async functions. so you have to write async keyword before function declaration.

like this;

```
async addEmpFn(empData, emp) {
  empData.name = emp.name
  return await empData.save()
}
```

Comment: thank you, It's work  but too many people give me answer. I've to mark the 1st. 
I very thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try to mention **async** before your funtion like below I mentioned

```
async addEmpFn(empData, emp) { 
    empData.name = emp.name;
    return await empData.save();
}
```

Comment: thank you, It's work  but too many people give me answer. I've to mark the 1st. 
I very thank you for your help

Comment: Cool.. you come up with problem is important...happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need an async await here, async await is needed when you want to wait for the promise to get resolved.

And also *return await* is an anti-pattern in JS until you don't want to use try-catch around.

Following code is the way to go, works same as the accepted answer.

```js
 addEmpFn(empData, emp) {
    empData.name = emp.name
    return empData.save()
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to write the same thing.